# @Value is not working for class that implements Condition as expected

Tags: spring

I have class that implements Spring `Condition` [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/test-conditional/blob/master/src/main/java/com/as/demo/config/AerospikeConfig.java#L26-L29).
when I run the [main](https://github.com/rajcspsg/test-conditional/blob/master/src/main/java/com/as/demo/app/AerospikeApp.java) app it prints the below output in console.

```
host = null
port = 0
${userstore.host} localhost
${userstore.port} 3000
returns true
```

The host and port which are annotated with  `@Value("${userstore.host}")` and  `@Value("${userstore.port}")` are null and 0 respectively but when I print `System.out.println("${userstore.host} " + System.getProperty("userstore.host"))` and `System.out.println("${userstore.port} " + System.getProperty("userstore.port"))` it prints the configured value correctly.

I've tried `@Value("#{systemProperties['userstore.host']}")` as well but no success.

what is the mistake that I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the class in your git repository. The Problem is the Class implementing `Condition`interface. The Spring container doesnt consider the class object as bean, so it doesnt perform autowiring and any `@Value` processing on the same instance. That is the reason your `@Value` fields are getting `null` values.

you can get the values from `ConditionContext` something like below:

```
conditionContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("userstore.host");
conditionContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("userstore.port");
```

or you can fetch the values using `java.lang.System`class as mentioned in your code.